# Array saved to core-data is empty after appending items to it

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I am trying to save an array to core data which is of integers(as input from users.) When I print the entity, the number saved is being printed but the array is not. here is the code.

```
@IBAction func logMood(_ sender: UIButton) {

let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let num =  Numbers(context: managedObjectContext)
    num.numberInArray = Int16(numberEnteredInSlider)

    var dataArray : [[Int: Int]] {
        get { return (try? JSONDecoder().decode([[Int:Int]].self, from: 
    num.dataOfArray!)) ?? [] }
        set { num.dataOfArray = try! JSONEncoder().encode(num.numberInArray) }
    }
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
        num.dataOfArray?.append(contentsOf: [UInt8(num.numberInArray)])
        print(num)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")

    }
```

And the output comes like this:

```
<Numbers:> (entity: Numbers; id:; data: {
    dataOfArray = nil;
    numberInArray = 3;
})
```

[xcdatamodel](https://imgur.com/gallery/d8UWq6G)

Comment: You didn't understand my suggestion in your previous question. The computed property `dataArray` must be located inside the `Numbers` class to map the `Int` array to `Data` and vice versa because Core Data doesn't support arrays directly. And what is the real array type? `[Int]` or `[[Int:Int]]`?

Comment: Wouldn't this be much easier if you had an entity instead with properties `key: Int, value: Int` to store the content of the array?

Comment: @vadian, sorry I didn't get it, I'm fairly new to iOS programming and this is my first personal project. it is an array of integers which will be passed onto another function. I'm not sure how `[Int:Int]` works, I copied it on stack overflow. also, i currently don't have a Numbers class, it an entity in the XCDataModel.

Comment: The `[[Int:Int]]` type was part of the singleton in your previous question. And the entity **is** the `Numbers` class. It's quite unclear what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: I'm sorry i should be more clear. mostly, im trying to make an array of integers `numberEnteredInSlider `, save that array in CoreData, and use it to make charts. also I do realize I should not have used the singleton. please could you give advice on how ot carry on from here?

Comment: also i tried this instead  `num.dataOfArray?.append(contentsOf: [UInt8(numberEnteredInSlider)])` but the output is still the same :(